# The package grub-common needs to be reinstalled

Tags: grub2, grub-efi, reinstall

i got this error "E: The package grub-common needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it."  This error is the reason why i can't install updates and applications from ubuntu software. How can i reinstall the grub-common and everything start works fine again.

Thanx Costas.

Comment: Is that the only error you get? It sounds like your system is not able to access a repo.

Comment: yes this is  the only error